# Iphone Debugging

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am getting the below error for swift app i made for IOS. I had setup notification using [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial) example. How do I debug this and know what the issue is?

```
Crashed: com.apple.UNSNotificationRegistrarConnection
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000013000001328

Crashed: com.apple.UNSNotificationRegistrarConnection
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x180cf9b9c objc_msgSend + 28
1  UserNotificationServices       0x183038b54 __destroy_helper_block_27 + 40
2  libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x1811298e8 _Block_release + 156
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x1810cd47c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1810d94c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1810d0f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1810cd47c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1810db914 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1810db0b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1812e5470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1812e5020 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: Any news on this? We are running into the same kind of bug. It's quite difficult to track down. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: same here...I have no idea how to fix it. It sometimes happens.

Comment: Have you had any success tracking down the cause of this crash?